# Returning XMLDocument from Ax2009

Tags: .net, axapta, dynamics-ax-2009, business-connector

I have a function in Axapta as follows:

```
static client XMLDocument GetXmlData()
{
    XMLDocument xmlReturnDoc = new XMLDocument();

    // Build XML Document

    return xmlReturnDoc;
}
```

This returns an XML document.  I’m then calling this from a .NET program using the business connector as follows:

```
Axapta ax;
object o;

ax = new Axapta();
ax.Logon(null, null, null, null);

o = ax.CallStaticClassMethod(“MyClass”, “GetXmlData”);
```

However, I don’t seem to be able to cast this to a System.Xml.XmlDocument in .NET.  Is there a way to do this, or do I need to return a string and reload the document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AX `XMLDocument` is not the same beast as CLR `System.Xml.XmlDocument`.

There is no automatic conversion between object types.
There are some implicit conversions of primitive types, but only one way.
See [How to: Marshal Between X++ and CLR Primitive Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc584291.aspx).

Reading [How to: Call Business Logic Using .NET Business Connector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa851743.aspx) leaves little doubt that the easy way is to return the XML string.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, you can pass the correct type into Ax

```
void netGetXmlData(System.Xml.XmlDocument netXml)
{
    XMLDocument xmlDoc = GetXmlData();
    netXml.set_InnerText(xmlDoc.text());

}
```

and call this AX method from CLR :

```
ax.CallStaticClassMethod(“MyClass”, “GetXmlData”, xmlDoc);
```

AX works correctly with the CLR data types - you can generate NET XML document on the AX-side.